# I Want to Edit lk partition to support fastboot binaries

Tags: android, binary-editing

based on what i found Oppo removed the fastboot binaries from my phone (Oppo A5s) and since the lk partition is the one that have it by default i would like to know how can i sort of inject the binaries into this partition

Comment: Your phone has a Mediatek SoC. For those devices it is common not to use fastboot and instead use the special Mediatek flashing software.

Comment: @Robert well is there any way i can have fastboot on Mediatek SoC